# Multiplying a infinite number with a rational number?

Tags: arithmetic

Please do not down vote this question. It may be stupid, but I wonder. Why is it that we cannot multiply $3.99999\cdots$ by $4$ and write $16,....$?

Comment: Yes that was what I meant. But it is late here so I am sleepy :)

Comment: Shall I edit it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Because it's not $12$ but $16$ ( Previously it was written as $12$ )

$$$$

> Way 1

$$\begin{align}x&=3.99999....\\
10x&=39.99999....\\
9x&=36\\
x&=\frac{36}{9}\\
x&=4\\
4x&=4\times4\\
4x&=16\\
\end{align}$$

> Way 2

$$\begin{align}x&=3.9999\cdots\\x=3+\frac{9}{10}+\frac{9}{100}+\cdots\\
x-3&=\frac{9}{10}+\frac{9}{100}+\cdots\\
x-3&=\frac{\frac{9}{10}}{1-\frac{1}{10}}\\
&=1\\
x&=4\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: So you can multiply $3,9999...$ by 10? That was what was interesting to me

Comment: You shift the decimal point

Comment: I do not know. I thought there was something like an epsilon delta proof that 3,999... was approximately 4, so that intrigued me

Comment: There's *also* that proof, but it's easy to prove that shifting the decimal point multiplies the value by $10$ for non-terminating decimals - essentially each "partial sum" (i.e. truncating the decimal) is $10$ times the truncation of the original string, so the latter will converge to $10$ times the former.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

$u_n=3.\underbrace{999\ldots9}_{n- \text{times}}$

$U=\{u_n\mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}\implies\sup U=4$

Comment: and it's strictly increasing :)